# undefined reference to `SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate'

Tags: c++, class, static-members

I stumbled upon this error while compiling my C++ coding.
here's my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount
{
private:
    static float annualInterestRate;
    float savingBalance;

public:
    float calculateMonthlyInterest()
        {return savingBalance+=(savingBalance*annualInterestRate)/12;}//adding the interest to savingBalance

    static void modifyInterestRate(float r)
    {annualInterestRate=r;}//modify the annualInterestRate

    SavingsAccount(float saving)//constructor with argument to set savingValue
    {savingBalance=saving;}

};


int main()
{
SavingsAccount saver1(2000.00), saver2(3000.00);//instantiate 2 different SavingsAccount object

SavingsAccount::modifyInterestRate(0.03);//set new interest to 3%
//printing savers' new balance after 3% interest applied
cout<<"THIS MONTH (3% INTEREST) :\n";
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<"Saver 1 balance : RM "<<saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
cout<<"\nSaver 2 balance : RM "<<saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();

SavingsAccount::modifyInterestRate(0.04);//set new interest to 4%
//printing savers' new balance after 4% interest applied
cout<<"\n\nNEXT MONTH (4% INTEREST) :\n";
cout<<"Saver 1 balance : RM "<<saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
cout<<"\nSaver 2 balance : RM "<<saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();

return 0;
```

}

the full error message:
C:\Users\NURULA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOIgGs2.o class exercise 3 no 1 ver 2.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN14SavingsAccount18annualInterestRateE[.refptr._ZN14SavingsAccount18annualInterestRateE]+0x0): undefined reference to `SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate'

and this picture is a snapshot of question i'm trying to do:
[image: the question]

the question didn't ask to make a constructor but i made one, assuming i need to to initialize the balance value, but i kinda got a feeling that's what causing the problem and error message. am i right? ....or wrong?

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `annualInterestRate` variable somewhere, with:

```
float SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate;
```

Static variables are like global variables; they have separate declarations and definitions.